# onClick={() => functionHere} vs onClick={functionHere}

Tags: javascript

Quick question:
What is the main difference between:

```
onClick = {() => functionHere}
```

and:

```
onClick = {functionHere}
```

I'm really confused since sometimes `() =>` works, sometimes I need to remove it and just right `functionHere` alone. Thanks a lot!

**Edit**

functionHere is like this:

```
const functionHere = () => {
    console.log("called")
    // some codes here
}
```

Comment: Well what is functionHere, is it a reference to a function? or is it operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's just a matter of thinking about what you're doing by using words.

Think about this way: `functionHere` vs `functionHere()`. What is the difference?
Without the parenthesis, it is a *reference* to a function while WITH parenthesis it is a function *executor*.

Now, like @merlin said, if you do this `() => functionHere` you're declaring a function that return a reference, not an executor (which shouldn't be very common anyways). In this case the onClick won't work, since the executor will not be called.

What is more common is this `() => functionHere()`. This will return the executor, which means that when the onClick event is called, functionHere will actually run (because of the executor).

Passing the reference straight into `onClick`works because it is built to run wherever function is passed to it. So passing a reference always works, passing a function that returns a reference doesn't. See?

---

**Additionally**
If you don't need to control which props you pass down, just use a reference. If you want to have some control over the props, use the arrow function `(name) => functionHere(name)`

Answer (score 1):

`() => functionHere` returns the function `functionHere` when executed, which means it is the same as just `functionHere`.

As you're not executing it there should be a syntax error thrown as you're assigning a value to an object without a key.

To avoid unnecessary function executions you should just write

```
onClick = {functionHere}
```

Note that this works because a shorthand literal notation was introduced in ES6 which makes this equivalent to

```
onClick = {funcitonHere: functionHere}
```

You should check out the [MDN docs on arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)