# How do i use functions that render elements (like icons) in a react native class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-component

I'm playing around a little with react native at the moment. At first I had the screens exported as functions, but then rewrote them to classes because it was easier for me to implement Redux.

My classes now look somehow like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from "react-native";
import { Input, Divider, Text, Button } from "@ui-kitten/components";
import { updateAuthStatus } from "../../store/actions/authentication";
import { signIn } from "../../services/authentication.service";
import { save } from "../../services/secure.store.service";
import Spinner from "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay";
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      spinner: false,
      identifier: "",
      password: "",
      secureTextEntry: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  toggleSecureEntry = () => {
    this.setState({ secureTextEntry: !this.state.secureTextEntry });
  };

  changeSpinnerState = (state) => {
    this.setState({ spinner: state });
  };

  setIdentifier = (text) => {
    this.setState({ identifier: text });
  };

  setPassword = (text) => {
    this.setState({ password: text });
  };

  googleIcon = () => {
    return <Ionicons name="logo-google" size={18} />;
  };

  eyeIcon = () => {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.toggleSecureEntry()}>
        <Ionicons
          name={this.state.secureTextEntry ? "eye-outline" : "eye-off-outline"}
          size={18}
        />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.signIn_screen}>
        <Spinner
          visible={this.state.spinner}
          textContent={"Anmeldung läuft..."}
          textStyle={styles.spinnerTextStyle}
        />
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text category="h5">Anmelden</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.form}>
          <Input
            style={styles.input_username}
            value={this.state.identifier}
            size="large"
            label="Benutzername/E-Mail"
            placeholder="Benutzername oder E-Mail"
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              this.setIdentifier(text);
            }}
          />
          <Input
            style={styles.input_password}
            value={this.state.password}
            size="large"
            label="Passwort"
            placeholder="Passwort eingeben"
            accessoryRight={this.eyeIcon()}
            secureTextEntry={this.state.secureTextEntry}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              this.setPassword(text);
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.text_password_reset}>Passwort vergessen?</Text>
        <View style={styles.form}>
          <Button
            style={styles.button_signIn}
            onPress={() => {
              this.changeSpinnerState(false);
              signIn(identifier, password).then((response) => {
                if (response.status) {
                  if (response.status === 200) {
                    save(
                      "credentials",
                      JSON.stringify({
                        identifier: identifier,
                        password: response.json.token,
                      })
                    ).then((stored) => {
                      if (stored) {
                        this.changeSpinnerState(false);
                        navigation.navigate("Home");
                      }
                    });
                  }
                }
              });
            }}
          >
            Anmelden
          </Button>
          <Text
            style={styles.text_not_registered}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SignUp")}
          >
            Noch keinen Account? Melde registriere dich hier.
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Divider style={styles.divider} />
            <View style={styles.view_social_login}>
              <Text style={{ color: "#a3a3a3" }}>oder</Text>
            </View>
            <Divider style={styles.divider} />
          </View>
          <Button
            style={styles.button_google}
            status="basic"
            accessoryLeft={this.googleIcon()}
            appearance="ghost"
          >
            Mit Google anmelden
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  spinnerTextStyle: {
    color: "#FFF",
  },
  signIn_screen: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  form: {
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  input_username: {
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  input_password: {
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  button_signIn: {
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  divider: {
    width: 100,
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#e0e0e0",
  },
  button_google: {
    color: "#8F9BB3",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderColor: "transparent",
  },
  row: {
    marginTop: 32,
    marginBottom: 32,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  text_not_registered: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: "#8c8262",
  },
  text_password_reset: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: "#8c8262",
    marginBottom: 32,
  },
  view_social_login: {
    width: 50,
    height: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    authenticated: state.reducer.authenticated,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateAuth: (status) => dispatch(updateAuthStatus(status)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignInScreen);
```

Only problem now is that my icons googleIcon and eyeIcon won't show anymore and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

When I exported my screens as functions I was able to just use the constant functions that returned the icons.

Doing it like so throws this error for me:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `FalsyFC`.
```

Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Calling a function that returns jsx is absolutely fine. Your implementation looks ok. I just caught the error that I answered below, it might be something with it.

Comment: Also, could you share the FalsyFC component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
eyeIcon = () => {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.toggleSecureEntry()}> <------ HERE
        <Ionicons
          name={this.state.secureTextEntry ? "eye-outline" : "eye-off-outline"}
          size={18}
        />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  };
```

By declaring  your function like that, you're calling it every time the component renders. You should always pass a REFERENCE to a function, like this `() => this.toggleSecureEntry()` or this `this.toggleSecureEntry`. I explain that a bit more in depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65164109/onclick-functionhere-vs-onclick-functionhere/65164217#65164217).